# Residue for non-integer order poles

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Is there any result for computing complex integral with non-integer order poles? For example,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{3/2}}dz,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)
\end{equation}
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. We know that it be calculated by using residue theory if the integrand is $z^{-m}$, $m=1,2,\dots$. What about (1)? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That is not a pole. In fact, that function you are trying to integrate is not defined in any punctured neighborhood of the origin as a holomorphic function

Comment: I think with writing $\dfrac{1/\sqrt{z}}{z}$ and with residue theorem we have $$\lim_{z\to0}\dfrac{-1}{2z\sqrt{z}}\to\infty$$.